# Inner Join Query Error

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT Product.prodName, Runs.buildNumber, Runs.prodDate
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Runs on prodId where Runs.runId=118
```

The above is my query for the schema:
[Please refer comment.It doesn't let me post images here]

It gives me an error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: `on` clause needs to be of the form `on table1.column1 = table2.column2`

Comment: _Probably_ `ON Runs.prodId = Product.prodId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small syntax error is there

Inner Join Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name where condition;
```

Update Your query as follows

```
SELECT Product.prodName, Runs.buildNumber, Runs.prodDate
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Runs on Product.columnname=Runs.columnname where Runs.runId=118
```

Just Go to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) link there is a clean and neat example of joins

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

The `on` condition must be a boolean condition.

```
SELECT Product.prodName, Runs.buildNumber, Runs.prodDate
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Runs on prodId=... where Runs.runId=118
```

So it must be `<column from Product>` = `<column from Runs>`

Answer (score 0):

You query needs to be like this

```
SELECT Product.prodName, Runs.buildNumber, Runs.prodDate
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN Runs r on p.prodId=r.prodId where Runs.runId=118
```

Answer (score 0):

From  Itzik Ben-Gan's book [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tsqlfund2012/)

> `INNER JOIN`applies a Cartesian product between the two input tables as in a cross join, and then it filters rows based on a predicated that you specify.

Based on above description, it must be predicate expression after `ON`, such as `Product.prodId=Runs.prodId`